# AngularJS: Call a controller after loading HTML content by ajax?

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I'm trying to execute a controller after loading the content by ajax :
Here,

```
    <div ng-controller="Hello">
        <p ng-bind-html="greeting.content">HTML</p>
    </div>
```

I'm call a controller Hello that replace HTML by :

```
<div ng-controller='MainCtrl'><div ng-bind-html='content'>XXXX</div></div>
```

So the controller MainCtrl don't execute after inserting..

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.content = "<b>this is bold content</b><p>with a <u>paragraph</u></p>"; });
```

How can I do it ?

Thanks you

Comment: ng-include don't execute after innerHtml "<div ng-include="'myPartialTemplate.html'"></div>"..

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

> Fetches, compiles and includes an external HTML fragment.

Example:

```
<div ng-include="'myPartialTemplate.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Or could be done using ngRoute. https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.24/docs/api/ngRoute